Error in Define Blazor Component Parameter
[Parameter]
public object Selected
{
    get => BindObject;
    set
    {
        if (BindObject == value)
            return;
        BindObject = value;
        SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(BindObject);
        
    }
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<object> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

In use:
<MyComponent @bind-Selected="person" />


Error CS1503
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<CustomBlazorComponents.Components.Pages.Home.Person>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

How do I have an EventCallback (for two-way binding) of type object?

The error is clear and object is almost never used in Blazor. It's rarely used in .NET in general since generics were introduced in 2005. Why not use Person? Is this a "generic" component?

On top of that, Selected should be just an auto-property.  The callback should only be called by component code if the value of Selected changes from the inside. Check the two-way data binding tutorial in Blazor University. Raising the event in the property could easily result in an infinite loop if the selection is changed from the outside.

You intent is not obvious, but it's unlikely the best way to approach your problem is with an object.
Here's a refactored version of your code that demonstrates how to use generics in a component.  I've used input for demo purposes to show how the bind works.
MyComponent
@typeparam TType
<h3>MyComponent</h3>

<input @bind:get="Selected" @bind:set="OnSet"/>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TType? Selected { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TType?> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnSet(TType? value)
    {
        await this.SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}

Home
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<MyComponent @bind-Selected="_value" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_value</pre>
</div>

@code{
    private string _value = "Fred";
}

